# Cloudformation "CreationPolicy" attribute not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I found a wonderful documenation on AWS site about how to make one instance come up completely and provisioned before second instance starts to come up. It is at https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/tag/cloudformation/page/2/

The documenation uses CreationPolicy attribute and cfn-signal to notify AWS Cloudformation that Instance1 has come up. I tried the code. It runs. But the issue is Instance2 comes up first instead of waiting for Instance1 to come up. This is the code and I attached the screen shot when the instances are coming up.

```
{
"AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
"Description": "EC2 Head Node Instance ",   
"Resources": {
    "EC2Instance1": {
        "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
        "CreationPolicy" : {
            "ResourceSignal" : {
            "Timeout": "PT10M",
            "Count"  : "1"
            }
        },
        "Properties": {
            "ImageId": "ami-3723c04f",
            "UserData":{
                "Fn::Base64":{
                    "Fn::Join": ["", [
                                        "<script>\n",                                               
                                            "cfn-signal.exe -e 0 ",
                                            " --stack ", {"Ref" : "AWS::StackName"},
                                            " --resource EC2Instance1",
                                            " --region ", {"Ref" : "AWS::Region"}, "\n" ,                                           
                                        "</script>\n"

                                    ]

                    ]

                }


            },              
            "Tags" : [
                {"Key" : "Name", "Value" : "QRM Head Node"}            
            ]

        }
    },
    "EC2Instance2": {               
        "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
        "Properties": {
            "ImageId": "ami-3723c04f",
             "Tags" : [{"Key" : "Dependency", "Value" : "EC2Instance1"}            
            ]

        }
    }


}
```

[image: Stack Events picture]}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify [DependsOn](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-dependson.html) attribute.

```
"EC2Instance2": {   
    "DependsOn": "EC2Instance1",            
    "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
    "Properties": {
        "ImageId": "ami-3723c04f",
         "Tags" : [{"Key" : "Dependency", "Value" : "EC2Instance1"}            
        ]

    }
}
```

The above snippet should resolve your issue.

*Edit-1* : cfn-signal + DependsOn

Create a cfn-signal to send out signals after your installations on Ec2Instance1 are completed. Please refer [cfn-signal documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-signal.html).

Now, create a `AWS::CloudFormation::WaitCondition` and refer it in Ec2Instance2. Here is a doc on how to integrate WaitConditions in your template [cfn-wait-condition](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-waitcondition.html).

Comment: If we are making sure EC2Instance2 will come up only after EC2Instance1 by using "DependsOn" Attribute, what is the use of  using cfn-signal in userdata section to notify that EC1 has come up?

Comment: Using `DependsOn` will ensure that EC2Instance2 will come up only after EC2Instance1 is "created".
On the other hand, you can use 'cfn-signal', if you want to do some setup in EC2Instance1 say install required softwares etc. and EC2Instance2 will only come up after those installations are done. In that case, 'cfn-signal' can be used.

Comment: Based on your question, I think "DependsOn" fits your requirement properly.

Comment: Let me tell you back and correct me if I am wrong. So if am doing some installation on my EC2Instance1, by using cfn-signal, I am telling AWS cloudformation to wait untill all steps are completed before the status of EC2Instance1 is turned to "Completed". Right?  Now coming to "Depends" attributes helps EC2Instance1 to wait until Ec2Instance2 comes up. . Did I get it property?

Comment: I updated the work flow in ans as Edit. let me know if it helps.